# Почему при эмулировании мобильного устройства в google chrome пропадает адаптив?

Tags: html, google-chrome, консоль, настройка

Я сейчас осваиваю инструменты разработчика google-chome. Помогите правильно настроить эмуляцию мобильных устройств. Сейчас у меня есть шапка сайта. Так она выглядит на ПК:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При Нажатии `F12`и сужении экрана шапка выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть появляется бургер, работают медиа запросы и т.д.

Но, когда я включаю эмуляцию мобильного устройства шапка на большом экране:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шапка на мобилке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему при эмуляции мобилки адаптив пропадает и контент просто уменьшается в размерах? Например, [в этом уроке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNvcGNx5zgQ&t=3360s&ab_channel=%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-IT%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81) у автора все работает правильно. Что мне добавить в разметку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` в head надо бы добавить